# Как полностью ограничить доступ к атрибутам и методам класса в Python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, ооп

Начал обучение ООП в Python и столкнулся с такой особенностью, что если указать режим доступа private ( `__<имя атрибута>` ), то всё равно можно получить и изменить значение данного атрибута, обращаясь следующим образом:  `obj._SomeClass__param`. Я узнал, что можно избежать данной проблемы переопределив методы `__getattribute__` и `__setattr__`. И так переопределять нужно для каждого атрибута или метода. Бывает более простой или правильный способ полностью закрыть доступ к атрибуту и методу класса?

Comment: покажите пожалуйста свой рабочий пример и объясните лучше, что вы хотите сделать.

Comment: @S.Nick На данный момент у меня нет примера, сейчас изучаю теорию. И при изучении не раз натыкался на такую особенность Python'a. Поэтому подумал, а что если мне нужно будет в будущем полностью защитить какие-нибудь атрибуты моего класса от изменения пользователем. Поэтому решил не откладывать этот вопрос и разобраться сразу.

Comment: Теория без практики мертва, а практика без теории слепа. (А. Суворов)

Comment: @S.Nick Вот пример библиотеки для датчика, которую я начал писать для практики ООП https://github.com/nulleach/test_class/blob/main/ADIS_.py . Например, мне очень нужно запретить изменять значение констант регистров и метода set_decrate в теле класса. Как это можно осуществить?

Comment: Это практический вопрос, или теоретический? С практической точки зрения это не имеет особого смысла: даже если вы полностью заблокируете возможность обращения к этим полям, никто не помешает кому-то полностью скопировать ваш модуль и сделать поля открытыми. В итоге для запрета случайного изменения внутренних полей достаточно двойного подчеркивания, для запрета "злонамеренного" изменения не поможет никакое ухищрение.

Comment: @insolor Это был чисто теоретический вопрос. Спасибо за Ваш ответ.